# How to add flexible attribute mapping structure

Tags: python

I collect data from different sources. At this moment I do it like this:

```
if (source == 'source1'):
    first_name = row['first_name']
    .. (a lot of mappings following the same structure)
if (source == 'source3'):
    first_name = row['data']['first_name']
    .. (a lot of mappings following the same structure)
if (source == 'source3'):
    first_name = row[0]['first_name']
    .. (a lot of mappings following the same structure)
```

This way I've very long lists with mappings following the same structure per source. Is there a way I can set the structure per source? Something like (pseudocode)?

```
structure['source1'] = 'row'
structure['source2'] = 'row['data']'
structure['source3'] = 'row[0]'

first_name = structure[source].['first_name']
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could register lookup functions in your structure:

```
structure['source1'] = lambda r: r
structure['source2'] = lambda r: r['data']
structure['source3'] = lambda r: r[0]
```

and then process data like:

```
first_name = structure[source](row)['first_name']
```